# Target Different Window c#

Tags: c#, window, target

Hey, I have been searching on google and I cant seem to find anything about targeting different windows in c#, I am using Visual studio 2010.

I'm not sure how to do this but I'm pritty sure it can be done, does anyone know where I can read up about it?

I need to be able to target a different program (like notpad for example), and simulate a key press.

Thanks.

Comment: Like Google, I also have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by targeting different windows? >.>

Comment: More details about what you are trying to do please...

Comment: I mean a program that I do not own, something else running on the PC. I need to target it so I can simulate a key press.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean interacting with different windows (possibly part of a different process), typically you would get a window handle (can be done in many ways), and then you can send messages and get data from those messages to those window handles.

For example see [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) which you would p/invoke from your C# app.

If you want to get updates on when certain events happen in those windows then you can use Windows Hooks.

Comment: Yeah, I mean something else running on the PC, I just need to target it.

Comment: @Crazyd22: As per my answer above. you need to be more specific as to what you want to do with that window if you want a more specific answer though.

Comment: Basically, when they click a button, I want it to target another window (for example notepad), and write some text in (simulate a Key press).

Comment: Yes so you want to use SendMessage and also look into the messages WM_SETFOCUS and WM_KEYDOWN or SendKeys.  See my answer here and the example code in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604898/net-sendkeys-to-calculator/2604919#2604919

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're on WinForms (same applies for WPF, slightly different code though).

In your project you have

```
Form1
Form2
Form3
```

At the top of your Form1 class, you define this code:

```
Form2 frm2;
Form3 frm3;
```

Assuming Form1 is your startup object you add buttons for "Show Form2" and "Show Form3"

In their respective code-behind you add code like this

```
frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();

frm3 = new Form3();
frm3.Show();
```

Same concept applies for WPF. If you're trying to do stuff with a window outside your application, the SendMessage Windows API is probably what you need to look into.

Comment: I mean a program that I do not own, something else running on the PC.