# Windows Forms\Console - Make Your KeyBord Type Words. Or Your Mouse to be clicked

Tags: c#

Well,

I am not sure if someone already asked this qusiton before. I was trying to look arround but noting came up. (if there is, please show me and close this. I am very sorry!)

For a few days now I am looking for a way that when I click on a button in my windows form in C# it will copy paste something to somewhere else.

The best way to expline this:

Lets say I got a Ms Word open, and I want that when I will click on a button in my windows form, after 5 seconds, it will write something in my word office. Of course I will open the Ms Word by my self.

Another thing: is how to make your mouse click on hes key?

edit:
When i use this code --

```
    int forhow = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    for(int i = 0;i <forhow; i++)
    {
        i++;
        SendKeys.Send("ספאמר על ידי פריזו - ספאמר על גירסא ראשונה");

        //ספאמר על ידי פThread.Sleep(1200);
        //Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

    }
```

well, its should do it only 1 time. is i write 1 in the text box. but, it is doing it about 50 times. and the stop. any one knows why? + . if you lick on the button, the program stops to work until she compltite all the "Send:".

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c). Also see [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604898/net-sendkeys-to-calculator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to force a mouse click, but you cam mimic the keyboard using the SendKeys class. All code that is not in between "//{" and "//}" was generated by visual studio.
Hope this helps!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//{
using System.Diagnostics;
//}

namespace ClickToWord
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //{
        Process imsWord = new Process();
        Timer tempTime = new Timer();
        int counter = 0;
        //}

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //{
            imsWord.StartInfo.FileName = @"";
            //Inside the "" put the path to the file/application. No need to escape it, because of the "@"
            tempTime.Interval = 1000;
            //The interval in miliseconds
            tempTime.Tick += new EventHandler(tempTime_Tick);
            //}
        }

        void tempTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //{
            char send = 'a';
            send += (char)(counter % 26);
            SendKeys.Send(send.ToString());
            counter++;
            //An example of looping through the alphabet. Send any string via SendKeys, and it will act as if the keyboard ent it.
            //This mimics keyboard strokes, and requires the document to have focus. That is why it is not the ideal way to do this.
            //To programmatically communicate with Word, use the Microsoft Word Object Model library.
            //tempTime.Enabled = false;
            //}
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //{
            imsWord.Start();
            //Starts the proccess
            tempTime.Enabled = true;
            //Starts the timer
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is AWASOME! really. but, when if i need to press the enter key? or the shift key, any chance?

Comment: Hmm..To press enter, you can just put "~".  Here is a full list:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx#alert_caution  @Alon M

Comment: This is very very good. Thanks again :). now all i have to do is wait for the mouse event, and i will close the topic :D. but you already answerd me, so i am sorry for not putting the V on you, i need the other answer aswell :(

Comment: ANOTHER PROBLEM. when is working, nothing else is working. isnt only me?

Comment: OMG. i am doing this:            for (int i = 0; i != int.Parse(textBox1.Text); i++)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("ספאמר על ידי פריזו - גירסא ראשונה");
                //ספאמר על ידי פThread.Sleep(1200);
                //Thread.Sleep(5000);
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

            } and its NEVER STOPS:(!!!

Comment: What do you mean nothing else is working?  Also, could you post the code that never stops in your main post? The comment formatting makes it impossible to understand.